# How to catch a document that is generated by a site (using R)

Tags: r, httr, rvest, rselenium

I am trying to download pdf files as follows:
(since this is a commercial site, I had to replace the url, username, and password below)

```
## login to the site first
library(RSelenium)
RSelenium::checkForServer()
RSelenium::startServer(log = TRUE, invisible = FALSE)
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(3000)
remDr$navigate(url)   # the url of the login page
remDr$findElement("id", "LoginForm_username")$sendKeysToElement(list("user"))
remDr$findElement("id", "LoginForm_password")$sendKeysToElement(list("pass"))
remDr$findElement("name", "start")$clickElement()   ## this is the login button
```

This is a website that contains data on interaction of firms. Knowing the api, I have figured out which page-name for each report that I am interested in. On the page is a "download pdf" button. When I click this button, the site dynamically generates a report in pdf-format and returns the report (with a random name, like "97da08491e3e41447f591c2b668c0602.pdf". I think it uses wkhtml2pdf for this. I click the button using the following code:

```
# pp is the name of a link for a given report
remDr$navigate(pp)
Sys.sleep(7) # wait for the page to load
remDr$findElement("id", "download-pdf")$clickElement()
```

When the "download pdf" button is clicked, the document is generated by the site, and then saved by Chrome. (the random name is different each time and there is no way I can use something like `download.file()` to get it) This works fine, except that the document is saved with this random name. Rather, I want to capture the pdf that is returned by the site and then save it using a more informative name (I have to do this hundreds of times, so I don't want to have to go through all the pdf's manually in order to find the report on specific firms).

So, my question is: *how can I capture a pdf that is dynamically generated-and-returned by a site and then save it under a name of my own choosing?*

(I apologize for not being able to provide the links to the site, but this is a proprietary site that I am not allowed to share publicly. However, I expect that this issue might be of use to more people and more sites).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the files in your download folder with R. I would simply list the files:

```
L <- dir(".",pattern="*.pdf")
```

If needed you can select the last PDF using the info from:

```
 file.info(L)
```

And then change the file name using

```
file.rename(identifiedName, meaningFullName)
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed does the trick. I was hoping to find a way to capture the document before it ends up in my download folder, but this is a workable alternative.